# автофильтр дат в сводной таблице excel

Tags: excel, дата, vba

Всем привет.
Есть макрос, оставляющий определенный диапазон дат в фильтре сводной таблицы.
Макрос работает ну очень долго.
Есть идеи как можно оптимизировать запрос?

```
Sub pivottable1()
Sheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DATE_PROLONGATION").ClearAllFilters
Dim StDate As Date: StDate = [N2]
Dim EndDate As Date: EndDate = [P2]
Dim dt As Date
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("DATE_PROLONGATION")
For i = 1 To .PivotItems.Count
    dt = Format(.PivotItems(i), "mm.dd.yyyy")
    If dt < StDate Or dt > EndDate Then .PivotItems(i).Visible = False Else .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Общие рекомендации.

*With/End With* - создание объекта "на лету", помогает ускорить обращение к оъекту и упростить код.

```
With Sheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    .PivotCache.Refresh
    .PivotFields("DATE_PROLONGATION").ClearAllFilters

    With .PivotFields("DATE_PROLONGATION")
         ...........................
    End With
End With
```

Какой смысл задавать дате формат, да еще на каждом шаге цикла? Дата - пятизначное число (количество дней с начала 1900 года) и для сравнения обычно не обязательно задавать формат. А вот *CDate* для преобразования иногда требуется.

Точно не знаю, как работает составное условие с оператором оператор *Or*: или находит первую *True*, или проверяет все входящие условия, а потом определяет, есть ли среди них *True*... Можно заменить на *And* и разграничить условия (при невыполнении первого не будет проверяться второе). В начале обработки одной командой все прячем, потом в цикле показываем нужное:

```
        If dt >= StDate Then
            If dt <= EndDate Then .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
        End If
```

Обращение к объектам листа медленное,. В показанной процедуре бОльшая часть времени тратится на отображение/скрытие строк. Но в массиве обработка происходит очень быстро. Пример обработки диапазона строк:

```
        If rRng Is Nothing Then
            Set rRng = Cells(i, 1)
        Else
            Set rRng = Union(rRng, Cells(i, 1))
        End If
```

После выхода из цикла отображаем строки:

```
        If Not rRng Is Nothing Then rRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Со сводными не приходилось работать в таком ключе. Возможно, такое и для них применимо.

Если даты отсортированы, достаточно найти пороговую(-ые) дату(-ы) и скрыть то, что не в диапазоне, не обязательно все в цикле гонять.

Нужен кролик для опытов.